# Create nested dict of unknown depth and initialize innermost key as list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, initialization

I want to create a dict of unknown depth, and initialize the innermost key as a list instead of a dict.

Code I'm using now (which works):

```
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
inputdict = nested_dict()

with open('inputdata.txt','r') as inputfile:
    inputobject = csv.DictReader(inputfile,delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in inputobject:

        try: inputdict[row['platform']][row['sensor']]['time'].append(float(row['time']))
        except AttributeError: inputdict[row['platform']][row['sensor']]['time'] = [float(row['time'])]

        try: inputdict[row['platform']][row['sensor']]['w'].append(float(row['w']))
        except AttributeError: inputdict[row['platform']][row['sensor']]['w'] = [float(row['w'])]
        ...
```

I want to simply be able to add to or initialize `inputdict[row['platform']][row['sensor']]['time']` etc. without the try/except for every column I want to save. Is this possible? I really just want to write one line instead of two so the code looks nicer...

Input data format:

```
time ms platform sensor P/S w x y z nl ns conf flag1 flag2
581083200 29000 C 1 P -0.16900 0.22519 0.77034 -0.57209 0 52 2 11000001 11000000
581083200 29000 C 2 P 0.87761 -0.13123 -0.44549 0.11875 0 32 1 11000001 11000000
581083200 29000 C 3 P 0.66907 0.13427 0.46785 -0.56162 0 88 2 11000001 11000000
581083200 529000 C 1 P -0.16911 0.22505 0.77021 -0.57229 0 50 2 11000001 11000000
...
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I will be plotting various combinations of these columns on a map.

Comment: I mean, what does your desired *dictionary* output look like?

Comment: @Ajax1234 oh oops, the keys will be combinations of `inputdict['A/B/C/D']['1/2/3']['time/w/x/y/z/ns']` for quantities that are unique to each sensor, or `inputdict['A/B/C/D']['conf/flag1/flag2']` for quantities that are common for all sensors on a particular platform.